# Exporting delimited Text file to Excel file using Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, export-to-excel

my text file is delimited by pipeline '|'

I want to export this in to excel file (xls) using a script in Unix

can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be,
Convert the delimiter | to ,
Save the file with csv extension
Open the file in excel.

Note: If you have , in the file contents other than token separator this idea will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert your file to .xls format then you will have to use apache POI library. It has perl support.
If you just want to open it in excel then you can directly use open with excel and set the seperator as |.
Or put all the words in " " and use , as the seperator. If it is within "" then comma within the text will not be an issue. But double quotes within the text will be a problem.
To avoid all these you can use some other ascii character as the seperator.